# Ubuntu AMi for AWS with patch for Dirty cow Vulnerability

Tags: 14.04, kernel, security, amazon-ec2

I am using existing Ubuntu Ami for my organization with 14.04 Ubuntu . My kernel for this AMi is 3.13.48 . This kernel is vulnerable to Dirty Copy on Write . So want to use the new AMI with this patch. This patch is available in new release in Dec 2016, And i want this patch in AWS. But not able to find the corresponding AMI. Please help to fix my existing AMIs or new AMI finding new AMI . The current AMI which is in use in ami-d85e75b0. And help if anyone find the AMI for the latest release notes in https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/ in community AMIs.

Comment: You can always patch your running instance and create AMI from it.

Comment: patching don`t fulfill my requirements as i need public ami for different aws accounts and different regions